# Should computational questions that can be easily solved with a calculator be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Many questions are purely computational and can easily be solved with a calculator.

The downvote tooltip says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is not clear or useful

Questions that can easily be solved with a calculator are like questions that can easily be Googled. They "do not show any research effort."

Is it acceptable to downvote those questions?

> What is 1 + 1 = ?

I think the example question above should be downvoted.

> What is 235.382 * (−4.69) + √(6)<sup>−3</sup> ÷ 168370

The second example question is in a gray area. Does it warrant a downvote?

Comment: Some certainly. But, is this really the first thing you need to know when joining the site?

Comment: So that I have a better idea of what sorts of questions you're thinking about, can you link to a couple?

Comment: "What is 2+2?" Absolutely downvote. "I have this complicated integral that Mathematica says is .... I tried this technique and it failed because... What can I do?" Completely different case, although it's still just a computation a complicated calculator can solve. Most questions are in between the extremes.

Comment: @T.Bongers Well the second question *can't* really be solved without a calculator, as it's essentially "How do I compute this integral *without a calculator*?"

Comment: It depends. This certainly can't be the sole reason for the downvote. Maybe the OP needs to know how to compute something without the calculator (i.e. dividing big numbers, taking square roots, etc.).

Comment: Post to meta: "Should questions stating imperatives be downvoted."  Yes.  "Should questions on meta about whether questions which can be answered using a basic calculator, with no effort from an OP, be downvoted?"

Comment: As with all elementary, homework-style, questions: they should be closed (not down-voted) unless explanation is also included showing the research effort or the reason it is interesting.

Comment: @gedgar why not downvote no research effort homework questions?